# Clicar no botão de Ações de cada row da tabela a cada 2 segundos

Tags: php, javascript, html, jquery, each

Tenho uma tabela com 4 colunas, sendo que a última um botão de ação "Enviar", onde o mesmo irá disparar um e-mail.

Preciso criar um loop onde a cada 2 segundos o Jquery clique na ação Enviar de uma row. Após 2 segundos o clique seria na próxima row e assim por diante...

Abaixo a tabela montada:

```
<table class="table table-striped table-hover table-sm">
   <tr class="bg-dark text-light">
      <th class="hidden-xs">Nome</th>
      <th>Email</th>
      <th class="text-center" style="width: 1em;">Marcar</th>
      <th class="text-center" style="width: 1em;">Ação</th>
    </tr>
    <?php
      $count = 0;
      foreach($result as $row) {
        $count = $count + 1;
          echo '
            <tr>
                <td class="hidden-xs">'.$row["customer_name"].'</td>
                <td>'.$row["customer_email"].'</td>
                <td class="text-center">
                   <label class="label--checkbox">
                     <input type="checkbox" name="single_select" class="single_select checkbox" data-email="'.$row["customer_email"].'" data-name="'.$row["customer_name"].'" />
                   </label>
                </td>
                <td>
                   <button type="button" name="email_button" class="btn btn-gray rounded btn-xs email_button btn-row-acao-enviar" id="'.$count.'" data-email="'.$row["customer_email"].'" data-name="'.$row["customer_name"].'" data-action="single">Enviar</button>                                    
               </td>
           </tr>
          ';
         }
      ?>
</table>
```

Comment: Importante postar um [mcve] do que tentou e descrever qual a dificuldade encontrada.

Comment: Eu sei das regras, porém não sabia por onde começar. Observe que eu postei um exemplo mínimo do que eu fiz!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//Indice para guardar em qual linha estamos,
//começa pelo 2 porque a primeira linha é do cabeçalho
let index = 2;

//Timer que será executado depois de 2s
setTimeout(function click() {
  //Pega o botão do índice atual
  const button = $(`table tr:nth-child(${index}) button`)

  //Se houver o botão
  if (button.length > 0) {
    //Faz o click
    button.click();
    //Incrementa o indice
    index++;
    //Reinicia o timer
    setTimeout(click, 2000);
  }
}, 2000);
```

Comment: Boa @Costamilam! Eu tentei aqui a partir da tua solução, porém ele só tá clicando na ação da primeira row, após os 2s ele não está clicando na ação da row seguinte... Desde já, agradeço a sua contribuição e vontade de ajudar.

Comment: @AndréAlbson esqueci de incrementar o índice, já atualizei a resposta

Comment: Excelente! Obrigado pela ajuda!